# Flutter cannot take picture while the camera preview is paused

Tags: flutter, camera

I am implementing a simple interface to take pictures in an app and I am currently trying to make it so that when an user takes a picture, the view switches from a `CameraPreview` to an `Image` widget. To remove jitters (since taking a picture can take a bit of time) I wanted to pause the preview as soon as the user takes a screenshot, so that the preview does not update while the picture is being taken.

However, it appears that if I pause the preview using `cameraController.pausePreview()`, I can no longer take a picture using `cameraController.takePicture()`, as If I do as follows:

```
Future<XFile?> _takePictureAndPausePreview() async {
    try {
      await _controller!.pausePreview();
      final file = await _controller!.takePicture();
      print("Photo taken.");
      return file;
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      showInSnackBar('Error: ${e.code}\n${e.description}');
      return null;
    }
  }
```

The statement "Photo taken" never gets printed and the function awaits forever. I looked into the code for both `pausePreview` and `takePicture` but I could not find any explanation for this behaviour.

Is it the case that I am trying to achieve this effect in the wrong way and this is the intended behaviour for this situation, or is it a bug?

I tried looking online for explanations / open bug reports but I could not find anything.